# Bookmarks: how to display both file content and bookmark annotation without closing the *Bookmark List* buffer window?

Tags: window-splitting, bookmarks

When in my *Bookmarks List* buffer (Bookmarks vanilla), I can place point on a bookmark, and call the function `bookmark-bmenu-switch-other-window`. This will open a second window, to the right, showing the content of the bookmarked file. The *Bookmarks List* buffer, with point, will remain visible in the left window.

However, if I call the function for an annotated bookmark, the *Bookmarks List* buffer closes, and two new windows appear side-by-side. The left one shows the content of the file, and the right one shows the annotation for the bookmark. The point is now located in the window to the left. The closing of the *Bookmarks List* buffer is very unpractical, since I often want to look into the file content/annotation of several bookmarks in a row without having to re-open the bookmark list every time.

I need a new function that can show both bookmark annotation and file content in the right part of the frame (split in two windows horizontally), while retaining the point and the *Bookmarks List* buffer in the left part of the frame.  Ideally, the upper right window for annotations should only be approx. 5 lines high.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or code!